# Problem summing an infinite series

Tags: bugs, symbolic, summation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

Calculating this sum on Mathematica 10.3

```
Sum[(-1)^(r - 1)/((a^2 + r^2)r), {r, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives the answer

$$-\frac{1}{2a^4}+\frac{\pi^2}{12a^2}+\frac{\pi\;\text{Csch}(a\pi)}{2a^3}$$

but this is not right, and there shouldn't be any neat answer like this in terms of elementary functions. As $a\to0$, the answer should tend to $(3/4)\zeta(3)$, which doesn't have a simple form in terms of a rational multiple of $\pi^4$, as suggested by the above formula. (Typically the answer would be expressed in terms of the digamma function.)

My question is, am I doing something wrong? How should one avoid this kind of problem and be confident that the sums returned are correct?

Comment: Bug still exists in Mathematica 10.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug to me.  The following is a workaround, at least on this example.

```
sum0 = Sum[(-1)^(r - 1)/((1. a^2 + r^2) r), {r, 1, Infinity}]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

```
(*
  1/(1. + 1. a^2) 1. *
    HypergeometricPFQ[
     {1., 1.,
      (0. + 1. I) ((0. - 1. I) + (1. + 0. I) a),
      (0. - 1. I) ((0. + 1. I) + (1. + 0. I) a)},
     {2., (0. + 1. I) ((0. - 2. I) + (1. + 0. I) a),
      (0. - 1. I) ((0. + 2. I) + (1. + 0. I) a)},
     -1.]
*)

sum = sum0 // Rationalize // Simplify
(*
  (1/(4 a^2))(Log[16] + PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - (I a)/2] - 
    PolyGamma[0, 1 - (I a)/2] + PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + (I a)/2] - 
    PolyGamma[0, 1 + (I a)/2])
*)

Limit[sum, a -> 0]
% - 3/4 Zeta[3] // FullSimplify
(*
  1/16 (-PolyGamma[2, 1/2] + PolyGamma[2, 1])
  0
*)
```

Comment: Note, FWIW: Changing exact expressions to inexact ones often changes the methods and decisions made by *Mathematica*.  Normally, exact expressions give better results (that often take longer to compute).  When faced with a bug, it's worth a shot trying an inexact coefficient.  Numbers like `1.` and `0.` seem like good ones to start with, since there is no round-off error in them to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this kind of bug common? I am new to Mathematica and this is pretty much the first thing I tried, so I am wondering how reliable it is in general. I suppose what might be helpful would be some guidance of the form "avoid infinite sums with alternating signs, because they are known to be problematic" or some such.

Comment: @AlexSelby Not very common.  Currently there are [9 questions tagged bugs and summation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs+summation). It might be better to say that *Mathematica* is sometimes overambitious, in that it has sophisticated algorithms that will attempt to tackle tricky cases and sometimes get tricked.  OTOH, this might be a programming error.  Hard to say which it is in this case.  You should report it to Wolfram support (menu Help > Give Feedback...).

Comment: OK, thanks. Looks like I was just unlucky then. (I wonder what caused it to come up with this particular formula.)

Answer (score 4):

Any of the methods for the [Regularization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html) option to [Sum](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) provide the same result with the expected limit.

```
Union[FullSimplify[
    Sum[(-1)^(r - 1)/((a^2 + r^2) r), {r, 1, Infinity}, 
     Regularization -> #]] & /@
  {"Abel", "Borel", "Cesaro", "Dirichlet", 
   "Euler"}]

(*  {(1/(4*a^2))*(HarmonicNumber[
          -(1/2) - (I*a)/2] - 
        HarmonicNumber[-((I*a)/2)] - 
        HarmonicNumber[(I*a)/2] + 
        HarmonicNumber[(1/2)*I*
            (I + a)] + Log[16])}  *)

Limit[%, a -> 0] // FunctionExpand // Simplify

(*  {(3*Zeta[3])/4}  *)

sum[a_] = (1/(4*a^2))*(
    HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) - (I*a)/2] -
     HarmonicNumber[-((I*a)/2)] -
     HarmonicNumber[(I*a)/2] +
     HarmonicNumber[(1/2)*I*(I + a)] + Log[16]);

Plot[sum[a], {a, -5, 5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{0, 3 Zeta[3]/4}]}]
```

[image]

```
sum[a] == sum[-a] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```